# Associative array in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, associative-array

I am trying to map a hostname to a queue manager name using the following array. I get an error with bad array script. What am I doing wrong here

```
declare -A managers 

while read -r mgr host; do
managers[$mgr]=$host 
done < file.txt

QMGR=$(cat qmgr.txt) 
host=${managers[$QMGR]}
```

I get the following error:

```
Bad array sub script at line 3
```

Comment: If the `done` is on the same line as the `managers` assignment, the syntax is fairly broken. If not: What is the value of `mgr` at this point? Easiest way to find out might be `set -x`. By the way, I get "bad array subscript" when the subscript is empty. Is this your error?

Comment: Thats was formatting error(done line). Ues bad array subscript is my error

Comment: Most likely, the subscript is empty.

Comment: Show us an example input which reproduces this error.

Comment: (a) See `shellcheck.net`. (b) Quote all variable expansions. (c) Show us the input files. (d) Print every variable immediately it changes, preferably like: `declare -p managers`. (e) Do you have a shebang? (f) The only subscript operation is not on line 3, so you are not showing us the script you are running.